Bilinear Constraints with Spectral Norm
Consider the following set of constraints
$$
\rho_{k+1} \leq \rho_k \|\tilde{A}_k\| + \varepsilon_k \|D\|, \quad \forall k = 0,\ldots, N-1,
$$
where $\varepsilon_k > 0$ is a constant, $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ is a constant matrix, and $\rho_{k}, \rho_{k+1} > 0, \tilde{A}_k\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are the decision variables.
My overall optimization problem is convex, aside from these bilinear constraints.
I am trying to figure how to relax these constraints into something tractable that can be solved using off-the-shelf convex solvers.
To this end, one technique that I am aware of is as follows: if the constraints are of the form $c \leq ab$ with respect to the decision variables $a$ and $b$, then we can use the Schur complement to equivalent write this constraint as the LMI
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & \sqrt{c} \\
\sqrt{c} & b
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0.
$$
However, trying to apply this technique to my specific constraints results in the following
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\rho_k & \sqrt{\rho_{k+1} - \varepsilon_k \|D\|} \\
\sqrt{\rho_{k+1} - \varepsilon_k \|D\|} & \|\tilde{A}_k\|
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0,
$$
which doesn't seem to gain anything for me, as I have the nonlinear term $\sqrt{\rho_{k+1} - \varepsilon_k \|D\|}$ in terms of the decision variable $\rho_{k+1}$ as well as the other term $\|\tilde{A}_k\|$.
So in summary, I am wondering if it is possible in any way to tractably enforce the original bilinear constraints using techniques of convex relaxation/Schur complement. If these techniques are not appropriate for my constraints, then how do relax/convexify them in general? Is the only way to resort to some kind of linearization methods?

Not only the bilinear term $\rho_k \|\tilde{A}_k\|$, say even $\rho_k$ is given and fixed, you have the norm (convex function) term which in on the RHS of the inequality constraint.
All elements in LMI must be affine w.r.p. to the original optimization variables.
